# Is it possible to get a list of all versions of an app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, version-control

the title speaks for itself. I play with GAE and some of my apps have versions like (1,2,3,4 and dev). So, is there a way to get all of them, so I could use it in my app to generate links to different versions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way to get a list of app versions from inside an app.

Comment: sad =(. there are
`os.environ['APPLICATION_ID']` and `os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']` but no approach to get all versions....

P.S. You sad '...from inside an app'. Is there a way from 'outside' (whatever outside means...)?

Comment: Currently, the only way to get a list is interactively, from the admin console.